# how to mark the passage of time?

Tags: python, time

I am working on my first original project, It's a virtual pet. The code is basically done, but I can't figure it out how to mark the passage of time. I want to do that so the pet gets hungry and bored over time. I tried making a function like this one `def manageHunger(): 
while True: 
myPet.hungerLevel -= 1
time.sleep(60)`
and many other functions, but nothing seens to work.
this is the entire code:

```
import random
import time
import winsound
import sys
import os
import textwrap
import random


class pet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.petName = ''
        self.hungerLevel = 10
        self.happinesLevel = 10
        self.sleepy = False
        self.sadnessLevel = 0
        self.dead = False
        self.entratainiment_level = 15

myPet = pet()

global playedTimes
playedTimes = 0

def titleScreenOptions():
    playerOptions = input("> ")

    if playerOptions.lower() == "play":
        setupGame()

    elif playerOptions.lower() == "help":
        helpMenu()

    elif playerOptions.lower() == "quit":
        sys.exit()

    while playerOptions.lower() not in ["play", "help", "quit"]:
        print('sorry, your command was not recognized by my system, check for any speeling mistakes and try again.')
        print('You can type "help" at any give moment to see a list of basic commands')
        playerOptions = input("> ")

    if playerOptions.lower() == "play":
        setupGame()

    elif playerOptions.lower() == "help":
        helpMenu()

    elif playerOptions.lower() == "quit" or playerOptions.lower() == "exit":
        sys.exit()


def titleScreen():
    os.system('cls')
    print("#=====================================================================#")
    print("# Welcome to pymagochi, the game where you raise your own virtual pet #")
    print("#=====================================================================#")
    print("#                              |>PLAY<|                               #")
    print("#                              |>HELP<|                               #")
    print("#                              |>EXIT<|                               #")
    print("#=====================================================================#")
    print("#            |created by: julio|      |2018, Brazil|                  #")
    print("")
    titleScreenOptions()

def helpMenu():
    os.system('cls')
    print("#=============================================#")
    print("# type the commands in order to execute then, #")
    print("# here are some of the basic commands for you #")
    print("#                 >check<                     #")
    print("#                 >feed<                      #")
    print("#               >go to bed<                   #")
    print("#              >play a game<                  #")
    print("#=============================================#")
    print("# the rest you can figure it out by your self #")
    print("# I mean, you are not that stupid, are you?   #")
    print("#=============================================#")
    print("")
    titleScreenOptions()


def promptUser():
    print("#############################")
    print("what would you like to do?")
    userCommands = input(">> ")
    validCommands = ['feed', 'play a game', 'walk', 'eat', 'drink', 'go to bed', 'help me', 'quit', 'exit', 'clear', 'play', 'fun', 'check', 'status', 'help', 'sleep', 'rest']
    while userCommands.lower() not in validCommands:
        print('sorry, your command was not recognized by my system, check for any speeling mistakes and try again.')
        print('You can type "help" at any give moment to see a list of basic commands')
        userCommands = input(">> ")

    if userCommands.lower() == 'quit' or userCommands.lower() == 'exit':
        sys.exit()

    if userCommands.lower() == 'clear':
        clearScreen()

    elif userCommands.lower() in ['eat', 'feed', 'drink']:  
        feedPet()

    elif userCommands.lower() in ['play a game', 'play', 'fun']:
        playWithPet()

    elif userCommands.lower() in ['check', 'status']:
        checkStatus()

    elif userCommands.lower() in ['go to bed', 'sleep', 'rest']:
        sleepPet()

    elif userCommands.lower() in ['help me', 'help']:
        print("===========================================")
        print("type the commands in order to execute then,")
        print("here are some of the basic commands for you")
        print("                >check<                    ")
        print("                >feed<                     ")
        print("              >go to bed<                  ")
        print("             >play a game<                 ")
        print("===========================================")
        print("the rest you can figure it out by your self")
        print("I mean, you are not that stupid, are you?  ")
        print("===========================================")
        userCommands = input(">> ")


def feedPet():
    myPet.hungerLevel += 1
    if myPet.hungerLevel > 20:
        myPet.hungerLevel = 20
        print("thanks, but I am full already")

    print("thanks for feeding me!!!")
    promptUser()

def playWithPet():
    if myPet.sleepy == False:   
        print("yeah!!! let's play a game")
        myPet.hungerLevel -= 1
        myPet.entratainiment_level += 2
        gameChoice()
        if myPet.entratainiment_level >= 20:
            myPet.entratainiment_level = 20
    elif myPet.sleepy == True:
        print("I don't want to play now, I am tired :(")

    promptUser()



def gameChoice():
    print("what game do you want to play? A math game or blank")
    game_choice = input(">> ") 
    if game_choice == 'math game':
        for i in range(8):
            number1 = random.randint(1, 30)
            number2 = random.randint(1, 30)
            answer = (number1 + number2)    
            print("%d + %d = ?" %(number1, number2))
            player_answer = int(input(">> "))
            if player_answer == answer:
                print("congrats, you got it right")

            elif answer != player_answer:
                print("sorry, thats the wrong answer")
                break


def manageSleep():
    global playedTimes
    playedTimes += 1
    if playedTimes >= 5:
        playedTimes = 5
        print("I am tired, put me in bed please")

        myPet.sleepy = True


def checkStatus():
    print("name: %s " %myPet.petName)
    print("hunger: %d " %myPet.hungerLevel)
    print("happines: %d " %myPet.happinesLevel)
    print("sadnes: %d " %myPet.sadnessLevel)
    print("entratainiment level: %d " %myPet.entratainiment_level)
    print("is he tired: %s " %myPet.sleepy)
    print("is he dead: %s " %myPet.dead)
    promptUser()

def sleepPet():
    print("z")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("zZ")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("zZz")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("zZzZ")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("zZzZz")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("zZzZzZ")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("zZzZzZz")
    myPet.sleepy = False
    print("Good morning, I feel better already")
    promptUser()



def clearScreen():
    os.system("cls")
    promptUser()

def setupGame():
    print("hello, welcome to pymagochi, where you are going to raise your own virtual pet")
    print("what would you like to name it?")
    name = input(">>")
    myPet.petName = name
    print("%s is a great name for a pet" %myPet.petName)
    time.sleep(3)
    os.system("cls")
    promptUser()


titleScreen()
titleScreenOptions()
```

Comment: "check for any speeling mistakes" - Is this intended irony? :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do - by using `sleep` the user won't be able to interact with the pet for the 60 seconds. Is that your intention? In that case, do you want a count down during this period?

Comment: That is one of the more profound question titles I've seen in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple 'Time' class that can maintain the time for you. Here is a simple mock up for you:

```
class Time:
   def __init__(self):
       self.current_time=0

   def getTime(self):
       return self.current_time

   def Tick(self):
       self.current_time +=1


time= Time()
print(time.getTime())

# Increment time by 2
time.Tick()
time.Tick()
print(time.getTime())
```

EDIT: This will be a possible solution if you want to manage the time yourself and not rely on the system time.

Comment: This example maintains ticks rather than time - the example will tick to 3 instantly. This could be suitable depending on what is desired though...

Comment: The example is just to show how the time will go forward. This will work if you want to manage the time yourself rather than relying on the system time.

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of time passed, you can store the value of `time.time()` for the initial start time. When you want to get the amount of time elapsed (In seconds), just subtract the starting time from the current time like so:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
while True:
    input("Press enter to get the time elapsed.")
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(elapsed_time)
```